# IF-ELSE condition in a function throwing TypeError __floordiv__, ValueError, KeyError

Tags: pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I need to read in bunch of i/p dataframes based on some conditions and then merge them and finally create dataframes as 'merge_m0', 'merge_m1', 'merge_m2' and so on.

In the actual code, I need to read about 20 dataframes. But, for simplicity and ease of understanding, I'm showing for 3 dataframes and below is the code which is working fine up to 'merge'.

However, for the IF-ELSE condition after the 'merge', it's throwing all kinds of errors. I'm using globals() to create merge_m0,merge_m1,merge_m2....dataframes and not sure how to go about with it.

**INPUT dataframes**

```
df0=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,4],'m0_val':[1,8,10],'name':['A','B','C'],'m0_orig_val':[2,3,4],'m0_int_dt':['07/15/2019','03/21/2019','08/10/2019'],'m0_bpo_dt':['10/15/2019','04/12/2019','06/08/2019']})
df1=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,4],'m1_val':[8,10,1],'name':['D','E','F'],'m1_orig_val':[2,3,4],'m1_int_dt':['02/11/2018','04/06/2019','11/22/2019'],'m1_bpo_dt':['02/15/2018','09/11/2019','12/14/2019']})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,4],'m2_val':[1,10,8],'name':['G','H','I'],'m2_orig_val':[2,3,4],'m2_int_dt':['10/01/2019','09/03/2018','12/22/2017'],'m2_bpo_dt':['11/15/2018','01/12/2019','08/08/2019']})
```

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

mydate1=datetime.date(2019,12,31)

df_list=[]
for i in range(0,3):
    df_list.append(globals()[f'df{i}']) #appending all the above i/p dataframes to a list

def comb_mths(i):
    dfa = df_list[i]
    dfb = df_list[i+1]
    dfma = dfa[dfa.iloc[:, 1].isin([1,8])] 
    dfmb = dfb[(dfb.iloc[:, 1].isin([8,10])) & (dfb.iloc[:, 3].isin([2,3,4]))]
    globals()[f"merge_m{i}"]  = dfma.merge(dfmb, how='inner', on=['id'])

    #if (globals()[f"merge_m{i}"][f"m{i+1}_orig_val"].isin([2,4])):
    if (globals()[f"merge_m{i}"][f"m{i+1}_orig_val"].isin([2,4])).any():
        globals()[f"merge_m{i}"]['diff'] = mydate1-(globals()[f'merge_m{i}'][f'm{i+1}_int_dt'])//np.timedelta64(1,'M')
        globals()[f'merge_m{i}']['mnths'] = globals()[f"merge_m{i}"]['diff']  - (i-1)

    elif (globals()[f"merge_m{i}"][f"m{i+1}_orig_val"].isin([3,5])).any():
     globals()[f"merge_m{i}"]['diff'] = mydate1-(globals()[f'merge_m{i}'][f'm{i+1}_bpo_dt'])//np.timedelta64(1,'M')
     globals()[f'merge_m{i}']['mnths'] = globals()[f"merge_m{i}"]['diff']  - (i-1)
        
    return globals()[f"merge_m{i}"] 

for i in range(0,2): 
    comb_mths(i)

print(merge_m0)    
print(merge_m1)
```

**IF-ELSE Logic**

In the above function after creating "merge_m{i}" dataframe, I need to check an if-else condition and calculate a variable called 'mnths'.
Logic of the if-else condition's pseudo code is below:

```
Ex: when i=0 (1st iteration)
if m1_orig_val isin (2,4):
    diff = (mydate1 - m1_int_dt)//(np.timedelta64(1,'M'))
    mnths = diff - (i-1)
elif m1_orig_val isin (3,5):
    diff = (mydate1 - m1_bpo_dt)//(np.timedelta64(1,'M'))
    mnths = diff - (i-1)

Ex: when i=1 (2nd iteration)

if m2_orig_val isin (2,4):
    diff = (mydate1 - m2_int_dt)//(np.timedelta64(1,'M'))
    mnths = diff - (i-1)
elif m2_orig_val isin (3,5):
    diff = (mydate1 - m2_bpo_dt)//(np.timedelta64(1,'M'))
    mnths = diff - (i-1)

Appreciate if anyone can please show me how do I add this if-else condition in the above function as I'm not sure how to do this using globals() and it's throwing bunch of errors? OR Pls let me know if there is any easy/better alternative to get this done. Thanks!!
```

**Edit**

*What I did:

Updated the if-elif lines in the above function and initially, it threw error at the 1st IF condition as "*ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()*"

And I added .any() to the if condition but not sure if that's right or do I need to do anything else

After adding the .any(), it's now throwing bunch of errors in the next line for timedelta I think as mentioned below

File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/timedeltas.pyx", line 1440, in pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta.**rfloordiv**
*TypeError: Invalid dtype object for **floordiv***

File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/timedeltas.pyx", line 539, in pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.parse_timedelta_unit
*KeyError: '/'*

*ValueError: invalid unit abbreviation: /*

Appreciate if anyone can help me in fixing this if-else statement or please share if there is any other(better) way of doing it in the above function . Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**I figured out solution myself:**

Below is the updated function. Earlier in the If-Else condition for calculating 'mths', I was using 'np.timedelta64' which was throwing all kinds of errors and now I've replaced that with different logic and also converted date columns to 'date' type. Now, the function is working perfectly fine and giving the expected results.

**Solution with Updated Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
mydate2=pd.Timestamp('2019-12-31')
df_list=[]
for i in range(0,3):
    df_list.append(globals()[f'df{i}'])

def comb_mths(i):
    dfa = df_list[i]
    dfb = df_list[i+1]
    dfa.iloc[:,4]=pd.to_datetime(dfa.iloc[:,4])
    dfa.iloc[:,5]=pd.to_datetime(dfa.iloc[:,5])
    dfb.iloc[:,4]=pd.to_datetime(dfb.iloc[:,4])
    dfb.iloc[:,5]=pd.to_datetime(dfb.iloc[:,5])
    dfma = dfa[dfa.iloc[:, 1].isin([1,8])] 
    dfmb = dfb[(dfb.iloc[:, 1].isin([8,10])) & (dfb.iloc[:, 3].isin([2,3,4]))]
    globals()[f"merge_m{i}"]  = dfma.merge(dfmb, how='inner', on=['id'])
    if (globals()[f"merge_m{i}"][f"m{i+1}_orig_val"].isin([2,4])).any():
        globals()[f"merge_m{i}"]["intnx_dt"]=mydate2-pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=i+1)+pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)
        globals()[f"merge_m{i}"]['mths']=(globals()[f"merge_m{i}"]["intnx_dt"].dt.year-globals()[f'merge_m{i}'][f'm{i+1}_int_dt'].dt.year)*12+ \
        (globals()[f"merge_m{i}"]["intnx_dt"].dt.month-globals()[f'merge_m{i}'][f'm{i+1}_int_dt'].dt.month)
    elif (globals()[f"merge_m{i}"][f"m{i}_orig_val"].isin([3,5])).any():
        globals()[f"merge_m{i}"]["intnx_dt"]=mydate2-pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=i+1)+pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)
        globals()[f"merge_m{i}"]['mths']=(globals()[f"merge_m{i}"]["intnx_dt"].dt.year-globals()[f'merge_m{i}'][f'm{i+1}_bpo_dt'].dt.year)*12+\
        (globals()[f"merge_m{i}"]["intnx_dt"].dt.month-globals()[f'merge_m{i}'][f'm{i+1}_bpo_dt'].dt.month)
    return globals()[f"merge_m{i}"]

for i in range(0,2): 
    comb_mths(i)
```

**Output**

```
   id  m0_val name_x  m0_orig_val  m0_int_dt  m0_bpo_dt  m1_val name_y  m1_orig_val  m1_int_dt  m1_bpo_dt   intnx_dt  mths
0   1       1      A            2 2019-07-15 2019-10-15       8      D            2 2019-07-17 2018-02-15 2019-11-30     4
1   2       8      B            3 2019-03-21 2019-04-12      10      E            3 2019-03-18 2019-09-11 2019-11-30     8
   id  m1_val name_x  m1_orig_val  m1_int_dt  m1_bpo_dt  m2_val name_y  m2_orig_val  m2_int_dt  m2_bpo_dt   intnx_dt  mths
0   4       1      F            4 2019-11-22 2019-12-14       8      I            4 2019-05-29 2019-08-08 2019-10-31     5
```